# After removing a package that came with a meta-package, will it be reinstalled in a future upgrade of the meta-package?

Tags: apt, package-management, metapackages

I'll describe this with an example:

1. I installed the lxde metapackage back in [focal (version 10)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/lxde)
2. I purge firefox from my ubuntu installation.
3. I upgrade the distribution to jammy and the lxde metapackage version [changes to 11](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/lxde)

Will that path of actions re-install firefox?

Comment: LXDE has been a Debian *sourced* package since Ubuntu 18.10, and *depends* requirements will control what is required. No `firefox` is **not** the only package that meets the *depends* rule(s), however if you don't have any requirement installed, `firefox` is the first (*in Ubuntu repositories*) and thus will be installed first.

Answer (score 0):

A command of the form `sudo apt install package-name` also installs the recommended dependencies of `package-name` by default.

firefox is a recommended dependency of the lxde (version 11) package. When you upgrade the distribution to jammy and the lxde metapackage version to 11 it will also install firefox as a recommended dependency of lxde. firefox is packaged as a snap package by default in Ubuntu 22.04 and later so that it will automatically be updated to the latest version. In Ubuntu 22.04 the firefox snap package is a recommended dependency of lxde which is an apt (.deb) package.